# Show Global SnackBar regardless of page

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am trying to show a SnackBar that appears regardless of where in the app I am. I did set up and GlobalKey on my root Scaffold, and I am able to call it to show a snackbar from anywhere in my code BUT since I am inside other Scaffolds, it does not show on these pages. The only way to view it is to pop the routes and go back to the main screen, where the root Scaffold is.

Is there any way I could show a SnackBar that's above every single widget?

This I am trying to do to be able to show a message for notifications received when the app is in foreground

Comment: Use `Scaffold.of(context)` to obtain the state of the closest `Scaffold`.

Comment: Alternatively, I believe there are some packages available that allow for this functionality.

Comment: Give this package a try. You don't necessarily need a scaffold to display a flash widget. https://pub.dev/packages/flash